# Best way to have a const factory for empty instance in Flutter's freezed

Tags: flutter, dart, data-modeling, freezed, flutter-freezed

I am trying to figure out the best way to implement a **constant** factory for "empty" instance of the defined model while keeping its original constructor strict (require all arguments without defaults).

The closest solution I could get is using [Union types and Sealed classes](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#union-types-and-sealed-classes) with an identical set of parameters.

```
const factory Costs({
  required bool valid,
  required String names,
  required String prices,
  required String subtotal,
  required String deposit,
  required String deliveryCosts,
  required String total,
  String? errCode,
}) = LoadedCosts;

const factory Costs.empty({
  @Default(false) bool valid,
  @Default('') String names,
  @Default('') String prices,
  @Default('') String subtotal,
  @Default('') String deposit,
  @Default('') String deliveryCosts,
  @Default('') String total,
  String? errCode,
}) = EmptyCosts;
```

So, this will keep my main factory strict, while allowing getting an empty instance via the second one. Important to notice, I also don't have to match sealed classes within the business logic code (all params are identical in both classes, so I can just access fields directly).

The are 2 points of concern:

- This is still not very lean. I have to redefine all params and prepend @Default decorator.
- You can use empty factory and still pass custom values, which ideally I would like to avoid. I would like an empty constructor not accepting any arguments.

Ideally, I would expect it to look something like this:

```
  const Costs.empty()
  : valid = false,
    names = '',
    prices = '',
    subtotal = '',
    deposit = '',
    deliveryCosts = '',
    total = '',
    errCode = null;
```

This actually works if you are not using freezed. With freezed, however, I need to redirect the constructor, which starts all the problems.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could actually do this.

```
@freezed
class Costs with _$Costs {
  const factory Costs({
    required bool valid,
    required String names,
    required String prices,
    required String subtotal,
    required String deposit,
    required String deliveryCosts,
    required String total,
    String? errCode,
  }) = LoadedCosts;

  factory Costs.empty() => const LoadedCosts(
        deliveryCosts: '',
        deposit: '',
        names: '',
        prices: '',
        subtotal: '',
        total: '',
        valid: false,
      );
}
```

Or else, if you want to pass the instance as a default value in a constructor, you could have a `static const` variable. Since it is const and immutable we cannot change the state of this static instance. Also anyway if we want to change the state in immutable freezed object, we use `.copyWith()` which obviously provides new instance without changing existing instance state. So i think this could help.

```
@freezed
class Costs with _$Costs {
  const factory Costs({
    required bool valid,
    required String names,
    required String prices,
    required String subtotal,
    required String deposit,
    required String deliveryCosts,
    required String total,
    String? errCode,
  }) = LoadedCosts;

  static const emptyCosts = LoadedCosts(
    deliveryCosts: '',
    deposit: '',
    names: '',
    prices: '',
    subtotal: '',
    total: '',
    valid: false,
  );
}
```

Hope it helps! Happy coding:)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will accept it, at least for now, since there are no other answers. It's been a while since I worked on it, but I think I tried this way. It works fine in general, but in my question I highlighted the need for **constant** factory. The reason is: there are other classes (non-freezed) that are immutable and they are trying to have defaults in the constructor. So, this way doesn't make the factory constant -> i cannot have it in another constructor as constant -> the class complains about its constructor needs to be constant because it's immutable, etc.

Comment: At the moment, I highly doubt it's possible to accomplish what I want. The analyzer is quite direct in saying that `Only redirecting factory constructors can be declared to be 'const'.` So it works as put it in my initial question, but I guess it will never work as yours.

Comment: Hey man, i get you. Check out my updated solution. I know its not a good way, but it will work since the freezed objects are immutable by default. However i'm happy to continue this conversation if you want.